# Miniprofiler .NET with mongo not showing query information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb-.net-driver, mvc-mini-profiler

Good afternoon.

I am trying to get [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) to work with mongo and mvc. The thing is i can see miniprofiler info in a page, i can see timing information but not querying column information. I would like to see the database accesses and queries..

I've tried with the example supplied on the website but nothing.

Anyone has tried this?

Thanks.